# Multiple Left joins in a query is returning incorrect counts

Tags: mysql

Unable to populate exact counts when I am using multiple LEFT JOINS to get the desired results like shown below

I wish to get the total counts of 'the number of tickets from t2' each 'manager_1' has, along with their names

FYI : Table 2 has aliases only for Engineers

Have tried inner,right and left outer joins to achieve the desired results but to no avail

Table 1 - t1

```
            +-----------+--------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
            | role      | alias  | name             | manager_1_alias | manager_2_alias |
            +-----------+--------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
            | engineer  | tommy  | tommy gun        | tim             | gegard          |
            +-----------+--------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
            | engineer  | sean   | sean penn        | ricky           | flo             |
            +-----------+--------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
            | manager_1 | tim    | tim robbins      |                 |                 |
            +-----------+--------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
            | manager_2 | gegard | gegard mousasi   |                 |                 |
            +-----------+--------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
            | manager_1 | ricky  | ricky hatton     |                 |                 |
            +-----------+--------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
            | manager_2 | flo    | floyd mayweather |                 |                 |
            +-----------+--------+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Table 2 - t2

```
            +---------------+-------+
            | ticket_number | alias |
            +---------------+-------+
            | 1234          | tommy |
            +---------------+-------+
            | 4567          | sean  |
            +---------------+-------+
            | 8910          | tommy |
            +---------------+-------+
            | 4321          | tommy |
            +---------------+-------+
            | 4422          | sean  |
            +---------------+-------+
            | 2288          | tommy |
            +---------------+-------+
```

Current Query

```
            SELECT
              j2.name
              count(t2.ticket_number) 
            FROM 
              t2 
              LEFT JOIN t1 AS j1 ON t2.alias = j1.alias 
              LEFT JOIN t1 AS j2 ON j1.manager_1_alias = j2.alias 
              LEFT JOIN t1 AS j3 ON j1.manager_2_alias = j3.alias 
            group by 
              j1.manager_1_alias
```

Desired Result

```
            +----------------+------------------+
            | manager_1 name | total_no_tickets |
            +----------------+------------------+
            | tim robbins    | 4                |
            +----------------+------------------+
            | ricky hatton   | 2                |
            +----------------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this

```
SELECT t1.name as manager_1_name, count(t2.ticket_number) as total_no_tickets
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.alias = t2.alias
GROUP BY t1.name 
ORDER BY t1.name ASC
```

Comment: thank you for the prompt response, I wish to get the Manager 1 name, the name column in T1

Comment: Yes, this is the **name** in **t1** `t1.name as manager_1_name` but I rename it wih the `as` to create the name of the **desired result**

Answer (score 0):

Does the following achieve what you need?

It's a join of t1 with itself to find names associated to the manager 1 aliases of engineers, and then with t2 to map engineers aliases to their tickets

```
SELECT tt1.name AS manager_1_name, 
       count(t2.ticket_number) AS total_no_tickets 
FROM t1
JOIN t1 AS tt1 
   ON t1.manager_1_alias = tt1.alias 
LEFT JOIN t2 
   ON t1.alias = t2.alias 
GROUP BY tt1.name
```

**EDIT:** removed two of the table aliases to make it easier to read